# Find the sum of closest distances

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity

For this task your code should take two sorted arrays of integers X and Y as input.  It should compute the sum of the absolute distances between each integer in X and its closest number in Y.

Examples:

```
X = (1 5,9)
Y = (3,4,7)
```

The distance is 2 + 1 + 2.

```
X = (1,2,3)
Y = (0,8)
```

The distance is 1 + 2 + 3.

Your code can take input in any way that is convenient.

The main restriction is that **your code must run in linear time in the sum of the length of the two arrays.**. (You can assume that adding two integers takes constant time.)

Comment: Can we use lists or streams instead of arrays?

Comment: @CatWizard Yes you can!

Comment: How is `1 + 2 + 3` derived from `X = (1,2,3)` and `Y = (0,8)`?

Comment: @guest271314 the closest number two each of `1`, `2`, and `3` in `Y` is `0`. Thus the differences are `1-0`, `2-0`, `3-0`.

Comment: @user202729 I clarified this in the question. In general, it is standard to assume you can add two O(\log n) bit integers in constant time unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is possible. Taking 2 arrays of numbers and finding the least differences will always take O(n) time, where n is the product of the length of the arrays.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix since both lists are sorted you can do it in O(n+m), because you iterate over list \$X\$, visiting each element once, and as long as you keep track of the element \$Y_j\$ closest to \$X_i\$, you can check against \$Y_j\$ and \$Y_{j+1}\$ since one of those is closest to \$X_{i+1}\$

Comment: Are the arrays always non-negative integers?

Comment: @Giuseppe No, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>70</s> 64 bytes

```hs
a%b=abs$a-b
x@(a:b)#y@(c:d)|e:_<-d,a%c>a%e=x#d|1>0=a%c+b#y
_#_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E1yTYxqVglUTeJq8JBI9EqSVO50kEj2SpFsybVKt5GN0UnUTXZLlE11bZCOaXG0M7AFsjXTlKu5IpXjrc1@J@bmJlnW1CUmVeiEm2oY6pjGascbaxjomMe@x8A)

### Explanation

First we define `(%)` to be the absolute difference between two numbers.  Then we define `(#)` to be the interesting function. In the first line we match when both lists are non-empty:

```hs
x@(a:b)#(c:d:e)
```

On our first case from here we bind `d` to `e:_` with `e:_<-d`.  This ensures that `d` is non-empty and sets it's first element to `e`.

Then if the second element of \$Y\$ (`e`) is closer than the first (`c`) to the first element of \$X\$ (`a`), we return `x#d` removing the first element of \$Y\$ and calling again with the same \$X\$.

If we match the pattern but don't pass the condition we do:

```hs
a%c+b#y
```

Which, removes the first item of \$X\$ and adds the absolute difference of it from the first element of \$X\$ to the remaining result.

Lastly if we don't match the pattern we return \$0\$.  Not matching the pattern means that \$X\$ must be empty because \$Y\$ cannot be empty.

This algorithm has order notation \$O(|X|+|Y|)\$.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

Here's how I would do it in \$O(\left|X\right|\times\left|Y\right|)\$ time:

```hs
x#y=sum[minimum$abs.(z-)<$>y|z<-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0K50ra4NDc6NzMvM7c0VyUxqVhPo0pX00bFrrKmyka3IvZ/bmJmnm1BUWZeiUq0oY6pjmWscrSxjomOeex/AA)

Comment: I clarified in the question that we can assume that adding two integers takes constant time.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s> 120 bytes

```python
X,Y=input()
i=j=s=0
while i<len(X):
 v=abs(Y[j]-X[i])
 if j+1<len(Y)and v>=abs(Y[j+1]-X[i]):j+=1
 else:s+=v;i+=1
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xT8MwEIXn3q84qUNsxUhNS0sxmK2sLAyJqg5pcqgOkWPZTmh/vXFQGe50790nvWdv4TKYdWyGllSWZbEUldLGjoFx0KpTXq3g56J7Qv3ak2Ell4CTqs@eVcfu9FAe9YkD6i/s8uKPqHhtWpze/pm8uFOyy1UBSL0n6XM1vehZW6dNQB9TONyTPt1IEhbB3dJe0JUanPtBOhuyAQ8f7wfnBjd/z47qb4Al0tVSE6jFYQypvkzWNs0OIivEVjxzwTbiUTxxSHotNkmvxJ7HXw)

Saved 4 bytes by moving to program versus function.

Meeting the time-complexity constraint is possible because both lists are sorted. Note that each time around the loop, either `i` is incremented or `j` is incremented. Thus the loop is executed at most `len(X)+len(Y)` times.

Comment: I clarified in the question that we can assume adding two integers takes constant time.

Answer (score 1):

### C (gcc), 82 bytes

```c
n;f(x,y,a,b)int*x,*y;{for(n=0;a;)--b&&*x*2-*y>y[1]?++y:(++b,--a,n+=abs(*x++-*y));}
```

This takes input as two integer arrays and their lengths (since C has no way to get their length otherwise). This can be shown to run in `O(a+b)` because either `a` or `b` is decremented on each iteration of the loop, which terminates when `a` reaches `0` (and `b` cannot be decremented below `0`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7NisIwEMDxu08xCEo@JmASxdXQ9UFcD2ml4sG4qIcMpc/eHbV03cMayOk/80sqc6iqrkuhFhkJI5bymG4qo6LQ1OeLSMUsxCCNKadTlZUzij5pa3cbrWkttC7RmIhJF7G8CpW15gEpQ9ud4jEJCc0I@LAJ2W53UEBjERYIqzYMhfriEeYIy758X7jVYjzZf6UxAn@QN4kvj3l@4hd2A@w4vcJ9mSF8/KvyDrmH6v6o/rm7QrC8b@2r6wf3nt7pzJJ/6PO73nY/)

```c
n;                     // define sum as an integer
f(x,y,a,b)             // function taking two arrays and two lengths
int*x,*y;              // use k&r style definitions to shorten function declaration
{
 for(n=0;              // initialize sum to 0
 a;)                   // keep looping until x (the first array) runs out
                       // we'll decrement a/b every time we increment x/y respectively
 --b&&                 // if y has ≥1 elements left (b>1, but decrements in-place)...
 *x*2-*y>y[1]?         // ... and x - y > [next y] - x, but rearranged for brevity...
 ++y:                  // increment y (we already decremented b earlier);
 (++b,                 // otherwise, undo the in-place decrement of b from before...
 --a,n+=abs(*x++-*y))  // decrement a instead, add |x-y| to n, and then increment x
;}
```

Some notes:

- Instead of indexing into the arrays, incrementing the pointers and dereferencing directly saves enough bytes for it to be worth it (`*x` vs `x[a]` and `y[1]` vs `y[b+1]`).
- The `--b&&` condition checks for `b>1` in a roundabout way - if `b` is `1`, it will evaluate to zero. Since this modifies `b`, we don't need to change it in the first branch of the ternary (which advances `y`), but we do need to change it back in the second (which advances `x`).
- No `return` statement is needed, because black magic. (I *think* it's because the last statement to be evaluated will always be the `n+=...` expression, which uses the same register as the one used for return values.)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 88 bytes

```
->(p,q){a=q.each_cons(2).map{|a|a.sum/a.size}
x=a[0]
p.sum{|n|x=a.pop if n>x
(n-x).abs}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X9dOo0CnULM60bZQLzUxOSM@OT@vWMNIUy83saC6JrEmUa@4NFcfSGZWpdZyVdgmRhvEchWABKtr8mqAfL2C/AKFzDSFPLsKLo083QpNvcSk4tra//8B)

Also, for fun, a shorter anonymous function that doesn't quite meet the complexity restrictions:

```
->(a,b){a.map{|x|x-b.min_by{|y|(x-y).abs}}.sum}
```

Comment: Could you explain in simple terms how this code works? I can't tell if it runs in linear time.

Comment: This fails the first test case in the question, as well as inputs such as `[5, 6], [0, 1, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
x=>g=(y,i=0,j=0,v=x[i],d=v-y[j],t=d>y[j+1]-v)=>1/v?g(y,i+!t,j+t)+!t*(d>0?d:-d):0
```

- It run in O(|X|+|Y|): Every recursion run in O(1), and it recursive |X|+|Y| times.

  - `x`, `y` are passed by reference, which do not copy the content
- `1/v` is falsy if `x[i]` is out of range, truthy otherwise
- `t` -> `d>y[j+1]-v` -> `v+v>y[j]+y[j+1]` is false as long as following conditions meet. And which means `y[j]` is the number closest to `v` in `y`

  - `v` is less than `(y[j]+y[j+1])/2`, or
  - `y[j+1]` is out of range, which would convert to `NaN`, and compare to `NaN` yield `false`

    - that's why we cannot flip the `>` sign to save 1 more byte
- `t` is always a boolean value, and `*` convert it to `0`/`1` before calculating

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBDoMgFATQfW/RHZRPC7WmrcnHgxAWRtRAjDSVED09xXUXk5lknu9St/Zf94l8CXbII@YN1YRkB4cCfEnCTTsDFhPftTcQ0aoymDQ8UVTyltrp4OwcwbNIS1@IVaK1Dbe0EbkPyxrm4TqHiYxES6jhbSjRFTzgaSg9/YE7VAcQ8Cp3/gE)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
x = {1, 5, 9};
y = {3, 4, 7};

Norm[Flatten[Nearest[y] /@ x] - x]
```

If you must create a full program, with inputs:

```
f[x_,y_]:= Norm[Flatten[Nearest[y] /@ x] - x]
```

Here's the timing for up to 1,000,000 points (sampled every 10,000) for `y`:

[image]

Close to linear.

Comment: This answer is a code-snippet since your input is taken as pre-existing variables.  You should reformat it to either be a sub-routine or a full program.

Comment: I'm also a bit suspicious that this works in linear time, do you have any justification as to why it should?  Mathematica tends to be rather opaque in the complexity of it's builtins.